# load-grunt-config Equivalent Module in gulp

Tags: gruntjs, npm, task, gulp

When I am doing my `grunt` configuration, I use the `load-grunt-config` module. It allows me to have each `grunt` task in separate files, which I load from a much smaller `Gruntfile`. Now, granted, it's not perfect, for example I can't find a way to define aliases for multitasks, but I wouldn't want to do task automation without it.

I have heard recently about `gulp`, which people are saying is better & easier than `grunt`. However, I have not been able to make the leap yet because I have not found an equivalent module to my sacred `load-grunt-config` (plus laziness). I have found a `gulp` equivalent to `load-grunt-tasks`, which allows you to skip the `loadNpmTasks` part of the `Gruntfile` as it finds the tasks for you, but does not move them to different files. In fact, `load-grunt-config` is based on this similarly-named module.

Is there an equivalent to the `load-grunt-config` module in `gulp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split your tasks in different files to ease organisation, the corresponding Gulp [recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md) recommends using the [require-dir](https://github.com/aseemk/requireDir) module.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this when I'm not too lazy... I mean busy. For now, +1 and if no one else answers today or something then accepted.